# Incorrect positioning of getBoundingClientRect after newline character

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slatejs

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu follow the cursor in a Rich Text Editor for the web. Using the following I'm able to get the cursor's coordinates no problem:

```js
const sel = window.getSelection();
if (!sel || sel.rangeCount === 0) return;
const position = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect());
```

However, if I try to use this after a `\n` character it returns the position of the cursor after the newline char rather than the beginning of the new line (where the cursor actually appears in the window):
[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

Edit: Based on the comments below here's a more in depth version of what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm currently building a text editor with React and Slate.js (https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate). It's a more robust version of a contentEditable component at its heart but allows you to drop in an editable text field into a page. Because of the node structure I'm using, I want there to be soft breaks between paragraphs rather than new `<div />` elements. Because this is non-standard behavior for contentEditable, it is very difficult to make a small example without recreating the whole app.

Edit (further responses to comments):
The raw HTML of the text element looks like this:

```html
<span data-slate-string="true">working until newline
see?
</span>
```

you can see that slate literally translates the break to a \n character which is what I think is causing the problem.

Comment: The newline character is at the end of the line you've created it. The cursor position does not reflect to the clientRect object.

Comment: Please [mcve]. In what event are you calling this code?

Comment: @Teemu does this mean that there's no way of getting the visual cursor position then?

Comment: Perhaps you can check what the actual selection contains - and if it has a newline character at the end, then modify the position of your menu accordingly? (Like set the x coordinate to 0 to start on the left again, and add one line height’s worth of pixels to the y value you got.)

Comment: I was writing once something to restore user selection accross multiple elements. I guess I know what happens but can you first share how actually HTML elements look like after this newline (not components)?

Comment: @GomiNoSensei No, it should be detectable, but not with `Range.getBoundingClientRect`. The standards for selections and ranges are still in progress, many properties of them are not standardized yet, that makes the task a bit problematic. You could add a bit more code, ex. how are the JS lines in the post actually executed. Also, can you elaborate "_soft breaks_"? HTML doesn't recognize `\n`, it needs an element with margins or `<br>`.

Comment: On which browser are you experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when using the default contenteditable of the browser there is indeed a weird behavior when the cursor is set to a new line: the Range's `getClientRects()` will be empty and thus `getBoundingClientRect()` will return a full 0 DOMRect.

Here is a simple demo demonstrating the issue:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');

document.onselectionchange = (e) => {
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel || sel.rangeCount === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  const position = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  floater.style.top = position.bottom + 'px';
  floater.style.left = position.right + 'px';
}
```

```css
#floater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #DDAADDCC;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" contenteditable>Type here and enter new lines</div>
<div id="floater"></div>
```

For this, there is a simple workaround which consists in selecting the contents of the current Range's container:

```
// check if we have client rects
const rects = range.getClientRects();
if(!rects.length) {
  // probably new line buggy behavior
  if(range.startContainer && range.collapsed) {
    // explicitely select the contents
    range.selectNodeContents(range.startContainer);
  }
}
```

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');

document.onselectionchange = (e) => {
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel || sel.rangeCount === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  
  // check if we have client rects
  const rects = range.getClientRects();
  if(!rects.length) {
    // probably new line buggy behavior
    if(range.startContainer && range.collapsed) {
      // explicitely select the contents
      range.selectNodeContents(range.startContainer);
    }
  }
  
  const position = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  floater.style.top = position.bottom + 'px';
  floater.style.left = position.right + 'px';
}
```

```css
#floater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #DDAADDCC;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" contenteditable>Type here and enter new lines</div>
<div id="floater"></div>
```

Now OP seems to be in a different issue, since they do deal with soft-breaks `\n` and a `white-space: pre`.
**However I was able to reproduce it only from my Firefox.**, Chrome behaving "as expected" in this case...

So in my Firefox, the DOMRect will not be all 0, but it will be the one before the line break.

To demonstrate this case, click on the empty line:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');

document.onselectionchange = (e) => {
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel || sel.rangeCount === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  const position = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  floater.style.top = position.bottom + 'px';
  floater.style.left = position.right + 'px';
}
```

```css
#target {
  white-space: pre;
}
#floater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #DDAADDCC;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" contenteditable>Click on the below empty line

Click on the above empty line</div>
<div id="floater"></div>
```

And to workaround this case, it's a bit more complex...
We need to check what is the character before our Range, if it's a new line, then we need to update our range by selecting the next character. But doing so, we'd also move the cursor, so we actually need to do it from a cloned Range. But since Chrome doesn't behave like this, we need to also check if the previous character was on a different line, which becomes a problem when there is no such previous character...

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');

document.onselectionchange = (e) => {
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel || sel.rangeCount === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  // we can still workaround the default behavior too
  const rects = range.getClientRects();
  if(!rects.length) {
    if(range.startContainer && range.collapsed) {
      range.selectNodeContents(range.startContainer);
    }
  }

  let position = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  const char_before = range.startContainer.textContent[range.startOffset - 1];
  // if we are on a \n
  if(range.collapsed && char_before === "\n") {
    // create a clone of our Range so we don't mess with the visible one
    const clone = range.cloneRange();
    // check if we are experiencing a bug
    clone.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset-1);
    if(clone.getBoundingClientRect().top === position.top) {
      // make it select the next character
      clone.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset + 1 );
      position = clone.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
  }
  
  floater.style.top = position.bottom + 'px';
  floater.style.left = position.right + 'px';
}
```

```css
#target {
  white-space: pre;
}
#floater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #DDAADDCC;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" contenteditable>Click on the below empty line

Click on the above empty line</div>
<div id="floater"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:
Insert a "zero width space" in the range and again call getBoundingClientRect.
Then remove the the space.

```js
function rangeRect(r){
  let rect = r.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (r.collapsed && rect.top===0 && rect.left===0) {
    let tmpNode = document.createTextNode('\ufeff');
    r.insertNode(tmpNode);
    rect = r.getBoundingClientRect();
    tmpNode.remove();
  }
  return rect;
}
```